# .htaccess Redirect Subfolder but excluse sub-subfolder?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect any URL request from /wp/ to /register/

However, if the URL request is /wp/wp-content/ or any subfolder of /wp/wp-content/, then I want to ignore the redirect and allow it through.

How can I do this simple conditional redirect using .htaccess?

I've tried for an hour with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your regex tightly enough then this is not really a problem

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp/?$ register [NC,L]
```

The thing to note here is that `^wp/?$` will only match `wp` or `wp/`

I hope that is clear.

Comment: Hey. I tried this but it didn't work. No redirect happens for wp, wp/ or and subfolders. What am I missing?

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this one out yet... Any help?